# Get more fields from database in node.js. Now only return id

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, database, typescript

The code makes a login and returns only the user's id. The question is how do I get another field in the database.

I need "header" from database.

> Onsubmit from form: 
>   [image: onsubmit]
>
> Authservice:
>   [image: authservice]
>
> RequestService:
>   [image: requestservice]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: What is `authService` ?

Comment: Above Code is only Frontend, The Database is handled by Node.js(Backend).
you need to correct in the API response(Node.js) by adding fields you want.

Comment: Ok @Andreas. Sorry

Comment: @JonasWilms authService is at core/request and is a class with constructor with router ('@angular/router'), requestService and configurationService with this.urls = new Map<string, string>(); this.urls.set('Login'..., this.urls.set('FilesList'... and this.urls.set('FilesFtpURl'...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from the backend. Just add the fields you want to return to the login user. eg `res.json({ payload: {name: user.fullname, age: user.age })` or you return the whole user object by `res.json({ payload: user })`